# How do I choose the number of digits in a variable in my scripts?

Tags: shell-script, grep, variable

Essentially, I am running a script that grabs a bunch of numbers from other files and puts them together in a useful way.

It currently works well, but it is printing every single digit from the numbers it is grabbing (grepping? is that a word?) and I would like to round it much earlier.

an example of the main idea is:

```
var1=$(grep.....)

echo $var1 >> output.dat
```

but this gives me something like 1.235215233462345345362 and I want many less digits.

Bonus question:

Some of the numbers returned are in scientific notation. Is there any way to change that as well?

ssh putty

Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) Release: 6.5 Codename: Santiago

Comment: [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Answer (score 4):

Use printf instead of echo :

```
$ echo "$a"
1.235215233462345345362

$ LC_ALL=C printf '%.1f\n' "$a"
1.2
$ LC_ALL=C printf '%.3f\n' "$a"
1.235
```

(`LC_ALL=C` is to make sure the decimal mark is always `.` (on input and output) regardless of the locale of the user (where it may be `,` instead)).